# « un seul accent, horizontal, qu’on appelle couramment l’accent plat » ?

Tags: histoire, typographie, diacritiques

Dans un article *Wikipédia* sur le [macron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritique)), on nous présente des échanges de ces regrettés experts, dont Nina Catach, au sujet d'un choix d'usage particulier dans la *presse imprimée* comme *remplacement* des accents grave et aigu :

> Aujourd’hui je pose la question : avons-nous besoin de deux accents,
>   l’aigu et le grave ? Notre presse imprimée, toujours à l’avant-garde,
>   a résolu le problème (autre problème séculaire) des capitales non
>   accentuées, et de l’aspect disgracieux des accents de guingois en
>   travers des titres, par une procédure, sans bavures : un seul accent,
>   horizontal, qu’on appelle couramment l’accent plat :
>   :DEUX BUTS
>   ENCAISSĒS
>   :UN OUVRIER TUĒ
>   :UN PIĒTON RENVERSĒ PAR SON
>   FRĒRE.
>
> [ Nina Catach, « Accent plat », dans *Les Délires de l’orthographe*,
>   1989 ]

En [contexte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapport_de_1990_sur_les_rectifications_orthographiques) de rectification orthographique, on a dressé un parallèle entre l'« accent plat » et la pratique de la « neutralisation de l’accent » basée semble-t-il sur des hésitations orthographiques. On présente aussi les avis, différents, de Jean-Pierre Lacroux et de Maurice Gross. Je n'ai pas accès au contexte de l'article original, ni à [celui](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_(diacritique)#cite_note-5) de 1992 où l'auteure suggère, peut-être plus formellement, le remplacement des accents grave et aigu par l'« accent plat ».

---

- En quoi consiste les « accents de guingois en travers des titres »
  dont traite l'auteur ; peut-on illustrer ?
- Pourquoi objectivement penserait-on que l'intersection de l'accent aigu et de l'accent grave soit davantage le *macron* ◌̄  que la *brève* ◌̆  ou le [*caron*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron_(diacritique)) ◌̌  ; en amont, parlait-on de tous les aigus et de tous les graves ; quelle est la portée du remplacement qu'avait suggéré l'auteure, et qu'est-ce qui motivait sa question « avons-nous besoin de deux accents, l’aigu et le grave » ; peut-on expliquer et qu'en pense-t-on objectivement, cette question est-elle toujours d'actualité ?
- Dans la *presse* (imprimée ou non) de ce millénaire, quel choix
  typographique ou usage s'impose-t-il, le cas échéant, avec l'accent
  aigu et l'accent grave **sur la lettre E** en *majuscule* ; est-ce l'[omission](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/academie-accentuation.html#Accentuation), l'« accent plat », l'[accentuation](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1438) etc. ; et sait-on dans quelle(s) proportion(s) ou a-t-on d'autres précisions sur ce qui pourrait expliquer le choix de manière très contemporaine dans ce domaine où le sujet des limitations techniques est dorénavant caduc ; la neutralisation de l'accent était-elle aussi fréquente avant l'avènement de la norme de fait du clavier [AZERTY](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) ?

Comment: Pour être clair, les accents "plats" n'existent pas à l'école :-) Ce serait invariablement une faute, le professeur voulant un accent "correct" à coup sûr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Les accents de guingois en travers des titres sont, je crois, simplement les accents habituels, qui sont obliques pour la plupart des gens, et de guingois pour ceux qui ne les aiment pas, le vocabulaire dépréciatif servant à la fois à décrire la chose et à en faire un problème, afin de pouvoir offrir sa propre solution. Les accents plats ayant un moindre déploiement vertical, on peut cependant leur trouver des avantages sans pour autant déprécier les accents habituels. Ainsi, parce que l'on peut réduire l'espacement entre les lignes d'un texte en capitales, on peut envisager de grossir la taille des lettres et augmenter la lisibilité à distance d'une une: ce peut n'être pas négligeable dans un choix éditorial. À noter cependant que la brève et le caron n'offrent pas cette dernière possibilité, ce qui les disqualifie d'emblée.

C'est une vérité généralement admise qu'un texte en capitales non-accentuées est un peu plus difficile à lire qu'un où les capitales seraient accentuées. Il y a même nombre de cas où une ambiguïté difficile à résoudre ou embarassante pourrait en résulter (BEURRE SALE plutôt que BEURRE SALÉ). Sans réduire à zéro les ambiguïtés possibles, il y a néanmoins nette amélioration en accentuant d'une seule manière, et l'accent plat est aussi bien plus lisible que pas d'accent du tout.

Différents éditeurs choisirons différentes stratégies. Je n'ai pas fouillé dans les statistiques, mais ai néanmoins trouvé deux exemples, le premier illustrant le choix des *accents de guingois*, le second des *accents plats*. L'un et l'autre me convenant, je ne vois pas l'utilité d'imposer une norme, quoique la discussion sur les avantages et inconvénients des différentes méthodes demeure intéressante et pertinente.

[image][image]

---

> Avant de continuer, il convient de mentionner que d’aussi loin que je me rappelle, j’ai utilisé le mot **tranche** pour désigner la partie visible des livres rangés dans une bibliothèque, celle où il est habituellement possible de lire le titre et l'auteur. Jamais personne ne m'a repris sur ce mot, indication possible que la terminologie de la reliure sort peu des milieux professionnels. Je ne serai pas celui qui réformera cette terminologie, n’ayant que de vagues et probablement inexactes connaissances de cet art fascinant, mais il sera bon de clarifier les termes qui seront utilisés ici, certains pouvant être diversement interprétés par ceux qui, comme moi, ne connaîtraient pas bien l'art et le vocabulaire de la reliure. Ce que j'appelais **tranche** (dont on trouvera encore des reliques dans mon premier commentaire ci-dessous), s'appelerait correctement le **dos** d'un livre.
>
> [image]
>
> On comprendra que ce dos n'est pas très large, et surtout qu’il ne se trouve à l'arrière du livre que lorsque celui-ci est ouvert pour consultation. Comme la couverture que l'on présente habituellement en librairie aux acheteurs potentiels se trouve elle aussi en position arrière lors de la consultation, il peut être laborieux de concilier le concept de position arrière habituellement attribué au dos (animal) à la dénomination de cette partie d'un livre. Il faudra, si vous êtes comme moi, vous contenter d'accepter le terme et tenter de vous y habituer.
>
> On supposera maintenant que l'arrière d'un livre n'est assurément pas son dos. **Plat verso** est un terme accepté, mais je préfère personnellement **quatrième de couverture**, beaucoup plus commun aujourd'hui (ce ne fut pas toujours le cas: les deux expressions sont en concurrence féroce jusqu'en 1979, moment où *quatrième de couverture* prend son envol et largue l'autre loin derrière). Mais ceci n'est qu'une parenthèse, puisqu'il ne sera pas question ici des quatrièmes de couverture... Un petit graphique ngrams pour visualiser la situation, néanmoins:
>
> [image]

---

**Comme le sujet m’intéressait, j’ai dédié une partie des jours suivants à rechercher des exemples**

Une petite enquête-maison sur ma collection de livres (dont beaucoup de bédés) et un peu en ligne semble indiquer une vaste majorité d'accents réguliers sur les capitales. Ainsi sont...

> - La collection Aire Libre de Dupuis, autant pour les auteurs (DE CRÉCY) que pour les titres (LE CAPITAINE ÉCARLATE).
> - Les INTÉGRALES de plusieurs éditeurs (Le Lombard, Dupuis, Glénat, Vents d'Ouest).
> - La collection SIGNÉ du Lombard.
> - La collection Bouquins de Robert Laffont: *FANTÔMAS*.
> - Les logos du *JOURNAL DE MONTRÉAL*, d'*AUX FRONTIÈRES DE LA SCIENCE*, de *QUÉBEC SCIENCES*.
> - Ainsi que plusieurs dizaines, voire quelques centaines de titres divers, d'ouvrages récents et anciens, de livres de référence autant que de romans légers. Je ne les nommerai pas tous, il y en a trop...
> - Continuant malgré moi mon enquête dans les files d'épicerie, où de nombreuses revues exposent leurs titres tapageurs et leurs photos d'acteurs, j'ai observé que plusieurs usent de ruses pour conserver les accents habituels tout en resserrant les lignes de textes: les accents sont réduits à de minuscules triangles rectangles, avec leur 90° et un angle extrêmement aigu en bas, celui-ci à gauche pour l'accent aigu et à droite pour le grave (je n'ai pas encore vu d'accent circonflexe). Ça semble un compromis satisfaisant autant le besoin de lisibilité à distance que la nature pointilleuse du français et des francophones.

J'ai glané quelques exceptions, le plus souvent des titres dessinés.

Accents plats:

> - Le **dos** de la nouvelle édition du CONCOMBRE MASQUĒ chez Dargaud (l'indication sur la couverture est en minuscules: *Le concombre masqué*).
> - L'album *LE ROI DES ZŌTRES* d'Achille Talon utilise aussi un accent qui semble plat, quoique ce puisse être sujet à controverse, car l'accent suit la très légère courbe du *o* qu'il surmonte (on n'y discerne cependant aucune trace de pointe).
> - Le *NOUVEAU GUIDE DU DĒPANNAGE* (Sélection du Reader's Digest), sur le **dos** et sur la couverture.
> - Le nouveau logo de la revue *protēgez-vous* fait usage de cet accent plat, mais n’utilise aussi que des minuscules.
> - Sur une note de légèreté et en réponse ludique à un commentaire sous la question originale qui indique que *« les accents plats n’existent pas à l’école »* et que leur utilisation *« serait invariablement une faute »*, j'indique que certaines écoles d’enseignement se permettent quelques écarts dans la partie la plus instantanément reconnaissable de leur participation à la vie communautaire, leur logo.
>   [image: ēcole secondaire LA CAMARDIĒRE]

Aucun accent:

> - *LE TRESOR DES ETAS*, de la série Kogaratsu chez Dupuis. Le style de chaque titre de la série varie cependant d'un album à l'autre, et plus loin dans la série, nous avons *LE PRINTEMPS ECARTELÉ* (sic), *PAR-DELÀ LES CENDRES*, *L'AUTRE MOITIÉ DU CIEL* et *LA STRATÉGIE DES PHALÈNES*.
> - La série Capricorne chez Le Lombard: *ELECTRICITE*, *L'OPERATION*, etc. Cette série a la particularité d'utiliser une typographie fixe et ouvragée, pour laquelle les accents ont été ignorés.
> - La série *LE REGULATEUR* chez Delcourt, au **dos** comme en couverture.
> - En couverture, quelques-uns des premiers albums du *GENIE DES ALPAGES* n'ont pas d'accent. Plus tard, le nom de la série n'est pas systématiquement présent, pas toujours en majuscules, et suit plus régulièrement la norme.

Enfin, j'ai déniché cet usage intéressant d'accents plats, dans lequel la position latérale de l'accent permet la distinction entre le grave et l'aigu!

[image]

Comment: Pendant mon enquête, j'ai observé, un peu en retrait du sujet principal, que les récentes rééditions du _Bon usage_, qui recommendent en §101d une majuscule au premier mot du titre d'un ouvrage, ont opté pour un tout-en-minuscules en tranche et couverture: _le bon usage_. Ce n'est d'ailleurs pas un cas unique: parmi les grandes références linguistiques, les _Usuels_ de Robert y vont d'une tranche en minuscules _(proverbes et dictons)_ et Larousse d'un _dictionnaire des difficultés de la langue française_. Les couvertures, tranches et unes semblent s'émanciper des normes habituelles.

Comment: Merci, que de fines observations et un propos éclairé avec un échantillon etc. ! D'autres réponses demeurent possibles pour explorer le propos de Catach plus précisément. J'aimerais comprendre ce que l'auteur voyait etc. en particulier vu votre remarque sur l'ensemble de votre l'échantillon. Les _tranches_, bien intéressant comme particularité... Merci encore !

Comment: Je crois que je n'ai pas utilisé le bon mot lorsque je mentionnais _tranche_. C'est ainsi que j'ai toujours désigné ce qui aurait dû être nommé le _dos_ d'un livre. Il n'est jamais trop tard pour comprendre que la tranche est l'endroit qu'a visité la trancheuse! :) Le _dos_ pour moi était le _plat arrière_, que l'on nomme aussi communément _quatrième de couverture_.

Comment: Nice additions! For *tranche*, I notice that the TLFi [donne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tranche) (§1. 3. g.) gives one more *tranche* than the diagram: *tranche de côté ou tranche de gouttière*, opposite the spine / *dos*.

Comment: "*donne*"? I wrote that comment too late at night.